# How to change sender email name in Django

Tags: python, django, email, django-oscar, django-email

I need to send an email from Django with 'Team Example' as a sender and by default, no-reply@example.com is used.

I have tried this as mentioned in other StackOverflow questions

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Team Example <noreply@example.com>'
```

in settings.py but it doesn't work.

Comment: The documentation specifies that this does not work for admins and managers. How did you test this? Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#default-from-email

Comment: How did you send an email?

Comment: I'm using Django Oscar project. Whenever a new user registers an email is sent to the  user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [django-oscar](/questions/tagged/django-oscar), you need to use the [**`OSCAR_FROM_MAIL`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/ref/settings.html#oscar-from-email) for:

> The email address used as the sender for all communication events and emails handled by Oscar.

This will thus be used if *Oscar* communicates with your users.

You can thus add a setting:

```
OSCAR_FROM_EMAIL = 'Team Blackweb <noreply@example.com>'
```